# Stop text wrapping around floated div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to  create a small gridded layout. However, when using floats, the text is actually larger than the floated div, and wraps around it.

Is there a way I can stop the text wrapping around the div, — but I still need the divs to be sat next to one another.

http://jsfiddle.net/4P35M/

```css
.left-note-feed {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: auto;
}

.note-container {
  margin: 15px;
}

.note-avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #000
}

.note-content {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-note-feed">
  <p>Show Notes Feed</p>
  <div class="note-container">
    <div class="note-avatar"></div>
    <div class="note-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, molestias nulla consequatur laborum harum obcaecati sunt voluptates. Soluta, accusantium, facere saepe minus quaerat libero nisi error magnam quidem enim eius!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="note-container">
    <div class="note-avatar"></div>
    <div class="note-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, molestias nulla consequatur laborum harum obcaecati sunt voluptates. Soluta, accusantium, facere saepe minus quaerat libero nisi error magnam quidem enim eius!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. In your fiddle I see text under the large dots.

Comment: Also, in your code above you have two `float` declarations for `note-content`. You need to add one to `.note-avatar` and remove both from `.note-content`.

Comment: @j08691 I think the author wants to place the avatar and content next to each other, instead of one over the other.

Comment: If you want the text to sit alongside the avatar you would need to specify a width for the '.note-content' div, eg 75%

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, it seems that you want to place the avatar next to the content, and not wrap the content beneath the avatar.

Since you know how large the avatar is, take the float off of the content, and set it's margin-left to the size of the avatar.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4P35M/6/)

```
.note-avatar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
}

.note-content {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

If, by chance, you actually wanted the content to wrap underneath of the avatar, then you could float the avatar left, and set the content `display` as `inline`:

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4P35M/9/)

```
.note-avatar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.note-content {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a width for the `.note-content`

```
.note-content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 285px;
}
```

Also it looks better with the padding removed from the `p` tag:

```
.note-content p{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

On a side note the `p` tag is unnecessary.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4P35M/8/